# linked list inside a linked list - node can't initialize

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

Im working on a c++ project for my data structures class, using nested linked lists.

I am supposed to write a program that reads student names from a file, and creates a linked list out of them. Each entry in the linked list should have the student's name, a pointer to the next student, and a pointer to a linked list of grades for that student. This program allows teachers to input grades for each student.

As for now, Im worried about finding the right way to get started.

The book provided a diagram which shows an example of how the data structure should be: [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bFwZ.jpg)

```
struct Grade{
 float score;
};

struct GradeNode{
 Grade grade_ptr; //points to Grade above 
 GradeNode *next_gnode; //points to next Grade NODE
};

struct StudentNode {
 string name; //holds Student name 
 GradeNode *grades;  //points to linked list of grades for this student
 StudentNode *next_snode; //points to next student 
};

StudentNode* head = nullptr; //head of student linked list (set to nullptr)
```

I believe how I have this layed out makes sense but when I run code below:

```
void appendNode(string n){

StudentNode *node;   //new node

node = new StudentNode;
node->name = n;
node->next_snode = nullptr;

//i just want to print out this node to see if value is initialized correctly
cout<<node->name<<endl; //this student's name prints out 

};
```

It returns an error saying "linker command failed". I feel like im initializing the node wrong but dont know how to fix it.

If someone has tips on how to find a solution, or a different approach for this task using linked lists, i would really appreciate it.

here is photo of error log
[image]

Comment: if someone can tell me how to upload photos from a mac photo gallery, I'll upload the diagram for more clarity! :)

Comment: Is all code in one file or in multiple files?

Comment: Please add the _entire_ error text to your question.  It sounds to me like you need to tell the linker to include the C++ standard library.  In that respect, this appears to be an issue compiling your program and therefore almost all the background reading you provided is irrelevant.  Either that or another symbol in your program is referenced but not available.  @Yang is probably on the right track there.

Comment: Try to drag n' drop the image into the question box.

Comment: Unrelated naming note: `Grade grade_ptr;` has a bad name because the variable is not a pointer and could lead to confusion when someone (maybe even you) sees `grade_ptr` in use later without the type, thinks that it is, a pointer and misuses it.

Comment: @Yang no its on one file for now

Comment: @paddy " linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)", i included <stdio.h> if thats what u mean

Comment: One option is to separate the linked list from the data it contains. If you are willing to delve into templates, you can make a `linkedList` class that can manage lists of students, grades, `int`s, whatever you decide to put into it. You can test it with something simple like  `int`, then, when you know it works, you can use `LinkedList<Student>` where `Student` contains a `LinkedList<grade>`. No duplication of code and no special rules for students vs grades vs whatever the teacher makes you use the linked list for next week.

Comment: @user4581301 good point! thank u :)

Comment: @Milton , Go up a bit further in the error message. That just says the linker failed. Somewhere above will be a much more detailed diagnostic explaining why it failed. If you don't see 
 what you're looking for, just grab all of the linker output and someone here will show you how to parse and interpret it.

Comment: @user4581301 i uploaded a picture of error log

Comment: A quick note on images: Don't use them unless they are supplemental information that help interpret the question but are not necessary or the question is about the image like, "Why's this green instead of blue?" There are many reasons not to use images. [Here are a few.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4581301)

Comment: If I may, I'm going to edit your question to make the image visible, but you should still refrain from using them. Copy the error text as text, paste it into the question, and surround it with `<pre>`/`</pre>` to preserve the formatting.

Comment: Yet another unrelated recommendation: If you are not going to use smart pointers, it is recommended to at least initialize at declaration, i.e. `StudentNode *node { new StudentNode };`. Also provide default value to all your struct members, so `nullptr` for all pointer types.

Comment: @user4581301 i appreciate it !

Comment: I didn't make the change. Mohit Jain got in and did the job before I could.

Comment: For future reference, even though error messages might look like a bunch of nonsense to the unpracticed eye, your life will become immeasurably easier if you learn to read and interpret them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From image it appears you have declared and used a function `buildList(std::string)` (in `main`) but never provide a definition to this function.

Solution: Give a body to `buildList` function.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when a function has been used in main without providing the function definition. Define the function before usage.